# After using navigator in a tabBarView page data is lost

Tags: flutter, navigator

I have a home page with a `tabBarView` with 2 pages, home and favorites. The home page has a `gridview` whose cells are populated by a `streambuilder`.  When clicked, they use Navigator to redirect to a detail page for that cell. I can tab between the 2 tab pages. After going to a detail page (from the home page) and back home, the `gridView` displays its data, properly. But after that, if I go to the favorites page and back home, the `gridView` data is lost.

I have tried `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and `wantKeepAlive = true` as recommended on SO.

The homepage widget doesn't rebuild when tabbing between it and favorites, according to the debugger and the data displays fine.

Going from the detail page back to the home page does rebuild the home page, and that is also fine as the data displays. Only if after that I go to favorites tab and back again does the problem occur.

I'm using bloc pattern and have a reference to the Provider's bloc in the home widget. It passes this to the `gridView`.

I'm using standard tabBarView and Navigator, in a SliverAppBar.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MovieProvider(
      euCollBloc: EuThemeCollectionBloc(API()),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(),

        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageOne(),

            PageTwo(),

          ],
```

```
bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    Tab(
                      text: "Home",
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: "Favorites",
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                    ),

                  ],
                  controller: _tabController,
                ))

.......
```

Navigator, used in PageOne widget:

```
.......

return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate:
                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => EuroCard(
                              preview: snapshot.data[index].preview ?? "",
                              title: snapshot.data[index].title,
                              description: snapshot.data[index].description,
                            ),
                      ));
                    },
                    child: Card(
.......
```

Using (probably too advanced for me) provider and bloc code from a tutorial by tensor on youtube.

The bloc:

```
class EuThemeCollectionBloc {
  final API api;

  Stream<List<EuThemeCollection>> _results = Stream.empty();
  Stream<String> _log = Stream.empty();

  ReplaySubject<String> _query = ReplaySubject<String>();

  Stream<String> get log => _log;
  Stream<List<EuThemeCollection>> get results => _results;
  Sink<String> get query => _query;

  EuThemeCollectionBloc(this.api) {
    _results = _query.distinct().asyncMap(api.get).asBroadcastStream();

    _log = Observable(results)
        .withLatestFrom(_query.stream, (_, query) => 'Results for $query')
        .asBroadcastStream();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _query.close();
  }
}
```

the provider:

```
class MovieProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final EuThemeCollectionBloc euCollBloc;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static EuThemeCollectionBloc of(BuildContext context) =>
      (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MovieProvider) as MovieProvider)
          .euCollBloc;

  MovieProvider({Key key, EuThemeCollectionBloc euCollBloc, Widget child})
      : this.euCollBloc = euCollBloc ?? EuThemeCollectionBloc(API()),
        super(child: child, key: key);
}
```

I tried using BehaviorSubject, but then I get a runtime error referring to the query stream in main page:

Error: The getter 'euCollBloc' isn't defined for the class 'EuroCard'.
 - 'EuroCard' is from 'package:bloc_example/euroCard.dart' ('lib/euroCard.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'euCollBloc'.

FIXED:
I needed to add super.build(context) to the PageOne (GridView) widget - it is extending State with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, so needed to be overriden. Sorry, didn't even post the culprit section originally.

```
class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne>  with
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageOne>{
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   super.build(context);
  var euCollBloc = MovieProvider.of(context);
```

Comment: It's good if you give a code example instead of explaining!

Comment: It seems that the default that is not being set. You may want to consider using a `BehaviorSubject` that keeps the previous value even if no data is sent to the stream to trigger the build. But some code would help.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have added code. (Tried BehaviorSubject, and get error about getter for query not being defined.). Would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it with a simple setState((){euCollBloc = euCollBloc)} in the PageOne (GridView) widget.

I can now do what I couldn't do before: load the home tab which displays the Gridview with the data cells, then navigate to a cell detail page and back home, tab to the favorites page, and tab back again home, and the data is still displayed.

As to why this fixes it, I am not sure. I thought the Provider pattern protects against setStates like this.

Comment: Well I fixed it by adding super.build(context) to the PageOne widget:

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne>  with
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<PageOne>{
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   super.build(context);
  var euCollBloc = MovieProvider.of(context);